# Trouble ordering a collection of objects by a numeric string value property

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, collections

So I have a class that contains a property called myNumber. It looks like this:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public int name{ get; set; }
    public string myNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

The value contained in myNumber can look like this `12-24` or `12-024`.

I would like to order a collection of these objects (`IEnumerable<MyThing> myCollection`) by myNumber descending but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

I tried `myCollection.OrderByDescending(f => f.myNumber)` but its not quite what I was expecting. I would expect `12-22, 13-01, 12-030` to order like this:

```
13-01 
12-030
12-22
```

Comment: Do you mean ordering by a number from first two characters of the string? Or the pattern is more complicated than that?

Comment: Why 12-030 greater than 12-22?

Comment: You need to be a little more explicit about what your rules are for how these are supposed to sort. Should they be in numerical order as if there was no -?

Comment: I guess the sort should first group the numbers by the digits on the left side and order them descending. After that happens they should order "within there groupings" by the digits on the right side descending.

Comment: The order you expect is not what I would expect. From a String perspective, I would expect the order 13-01, 13-22, 12-030 (descending)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order it like a [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx). Therefore you can split by `'-'` and use the first part as major- and the last part as minor version:

```
var orderedLikeVersion = myCollection
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Thing = t,
        Parts = t.myNumber.Split('-')
    }).Select(x => new
    {
        x.Thing,
        Version = new Version(int.Parse(x.Parts[0]), int.Parse(x.Parts[1]))
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
    .Select(x => x.Thing);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/I5z0Jq) with your desired result.

Comment: Thats brilliant. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you got this order?

```
13-01 
12-22
12-030
```

This would be correct by alphabetic conventions.  12-2* is greater than 12-0* since 2 comes after 0.

It also *seems* correct by numeric conventions, since 22 is also greater than 03, and 2 is greater than 0.

So I'm not sure in your expected ordering, why you interpret 12-030 as being greater than 12-22?  Is the part after the hyphen supposed to allow leading zeros to be truncated?  If you did that, then 12-30 would equal 12-030 and I would ask myself, what is the purpose of the leading 0.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. The leading zero of the digits on the right side of the dash are whats throwing off the order. People are allowed to enter a custom number and I am guessing thats how the data ended up this way. I suppose I could go in and attempt to clean this up but I am afraid that the system sees 12-030 and 12-30 as different numbers even though they are the same.